# Appending the values of multiple columns into one whilst retaining UIDs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table structured as below:

```
UID|ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD
```

I want to restructure so that all columns are combined (appended) into one, retaining the UID of each as below:

```
UID|ColA
UID|ColB
UID|ColC
UID|ColD
```

I'm very new to Pandas and was wondering how this could be done? Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show more of the dataframe or even better, a way to create an example dataframe like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have a dataframe `df`, created as below:

```
In [1] : df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), 
                           columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
In [2] : df                                                                                                                                                   
Out[2] : 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

you could try doing this:

```
In [3] : df.melt("a").sort_values("a")                                                                                                                        
Out[3] : 
   a variable  value
0  1        b      2
3  1        c      3
1  4        b      5
4  4        c      6
2  7        b      8
5  7        c      9
```

where the sorting might be optional in your case. Also, you should swap `"a"` for the name of your column containing the `UID` values.

You can additionally drop the autogenerated `variable` column too, so the final solution would be:

```
In [4] : df.melt("a").sort_values("a").drop("variable", axis=1)                                                                                               
Out[4] : 
   a  value
0  1      2
3  1      3
1  4      5
4  4      6
2  7      8
5  7      9
```

---

From what I remember, the `melt` functionality is inspired on the *melt* function in the `R` programming language, where DataFrames are one of the core built-in data-types. It is really useful for plotting using the ggplot library (in R).